# how to show a button automatically after item is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So upon a button click, i will show something and i want to check if that item is shown but I have one other similar condition to be met as well before the button can be automatically shown.

Html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control tryy4" id="idNumber1" name="num1" 
                                                   required 
                                                   data-error="Value is required">

//when button is pressed, item with id="p4" will be displayed. same goes to the p5 item.

<a href="" class="btn btn-success" id="submit4" style="float: right">Submit</a>
<p style="color: blue; display: none" id="p4">circular path</p>

<input type="text" class="form-control tryy5" id="idNumber1" name="num1" 
                                           required 
                                           data-error="Value is required">
<a href="" class="btn btn-success" id="submit5" style="float: right">Submit</a>
<p style="color: blue; display: none" id="p5">142 μm(acceptable range..)</p>

//this is the button that will be shown automatically after item with id="p4" is shown

<a href='' style='margin-left: 83vw; display: none' id="nextsect" class="btn btn-primary">Next Section</a>
```

Javascript:

```
    //code to show item p4 on button click:

    $("#submit4").click(function () {
            var value = $(".tryy4").val();
            if (value !== "") {
                document.getElementById('p4').style.display = "block";
            }
        });

    $("#submit5").click(function () {
        var value = $(".tryy5").val();
        if (value !== "") {
            document.getElementById('p5').style.display = "block";
        }
    });

    //code to show another button automatically after p4 is shown 

    var isVisible = document.getElementById("p4").style.display === "block";
        if (isVisible === true) {
            document.getElementById("nextsect").style.display = "block";
        }
```

The thing is that the button doesnt automatically shown unless an action is initiated because the code works..

Comment: u mix a lot of jquery and javascript, why don't you move ur  `document.getElementById("nextsect").style.display = "block"`; into your `#submit4` click event?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understood your question, but it seems you want the following: When you click submit, it should show the "circular path" div as well as the "Next section" button instead of submitting the form / going to the next page.

To accomplish this, you could do the following:

- Add `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form from submitting.
- Move the logic to display `nextsect` into the event handler.

Example:

```
$("#submit4").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = $(".tryy4").val();
  if (value !== "") {
    document.getElementById('p4').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("nextsect").style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

Let me know if that helps!

https://jsfiddle.net/jkp8dbom/2/

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're setting `#p4` to `block` inside of the conditional that checks whether there is content inside of `.tryy4`, and then simply checking whether `#p4` has changed, why not simply change the display of both elements inside the same conditional?

```js
$("#submit4").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = $(".tryy4").val();
  if (value !== "") {
    document.getElementById('p4').style.display = "block";
    /* Some other condition */
    if (1 === 1) {
      document.getElementById("nextsect").style.display = "block";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control tryy4" id="idNumber1" name="num1" required data-error="Value is required">
<a href="" class="btn btn-success" id="submit4" style="float: right">Submit</a>
<p style="color: blue; display: none" id="p4">circular path</p>
<a href='' style='margin-left: 83vw; display: none' id="nextsect" class="btn btn-primary">Next Section</a>
```

This results in fewer lines of JavaScript, and makes for a much more obvious 'flow' of the logic. Assuming you want to only display the second element when a secondary condition is met, you can just nest that logic inside of the `value` check (or alternatively, make use of AND (`&&`)).

Note that considering you're using an `<a>` tag for your button (which is strange in itself), you'll also need to prevent the default link behaviour by passing through `e` as a function parameter and calling **[`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)**.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: because i have several other conditions to be met first before showing the next section button. After all conditions are met then next section button will be shown automatically

Comment: You can nest an `if` conditional in that case. I've updated my answer to cover that.